# Is there any thread limit on CompletableFuture.runAsync

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, threadpool, completable-future

I have a Rest api, in which it calls a async call like below

```
 CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                        // method call or code to be async.
                     try {
                            logger.info("======Before Async method call======with studySchemaEventId: "+enrollmentStudySchemaEventId);
                            this.performSimulation(studyId, enrollmentStudySchemaEventId, cloneOfFile, simulationRunInfo, totalAccrual);
                            logger.info("======After Async method call======with studySchemaEventId: "+enrollmentStudySchemaEventId);
                        } catch (SimulationException e) {
                            logger.error("Error running Async call for performSimulation()", e);
                        }
                    });
```

when i call Rest api, it executed async call correctly.
But i have a case where i called Rest Api, 4 times and it executed Async call for 3 and for the 4th Api call i dont see Async method being called.

Is there any limit on runAsync() call ? or why is it not calling Async method after 3 calls ?

Here is the Rest API call:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/trigger")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)  
    @ApiOperation(value = "Trigger Simulation",  tags = "Study Event Simulation")
    public Response triggerSimulation( 
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail ,
            @FormDataParam("simulationRunInfo") SimulationRunInfo simulationRunInfo
  
    ) 
    {

// some other logic
// Async code here

}
```

Comment: How do you compose the 4 calls? Can you attach the code?

Comment: update code @polypiel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have encountered is the number of threads configured in the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`.

The task assigned to `runAsSync` is completed by the `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`. This pool is configured on the basis of the number of cores in your host computer. It seems that you have 4 cores.

By default, the size of the common pool:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() - 1
```

You can update the size:

```
-Djava.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=8
```

Alternatively you can use the overloaded [runAsSync](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable,java.util.concurrent.Executor)) with the executors argument.

Comment: you mean i can pass some fixed thread limit like below :
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

Comment: you could do that or you could use the system argument -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8. Note: you have to ultimately understand the limitations of your host and your workload.

Comment: Sure let me try that. my local works without any configuration. But i deploy on DEV server , i had this issue

Comment: It should call the 4th time as well. Could be delayed but it should. What is the calling code look like?

Comment: i accepted answer as some of code worked. on the UI we have button which calls the endpoint.